# How execute a function every hour and add the results into a database in Rails?

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, automatic-storage

Maybe it's a very simple Question, but I don't know how to solve it. :-) 
Is it possible that a rails app executes a function every hour which looks i.e. for clients in a network and add this data into a log database?

Do I have to use a cronjob or something like that? Or is there a nice gem in rails or something else? I looked for a solution in google but I didn't find one for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler). Both work great.